# text classification : comparing classification reports

Tags: classification, confusion-matrix, text-classification

I have a 4-leabelled text classification problem.

Could someone help me choose among the below text classifiers ?

I was advised to select the second one ( the one which uses both unigrams and bigrams ) but I cannot really see why.

[image]

Comment: What is the problem statement? What is being predicted here?

Comment: I have built two text classifiers for a reduced version ( 4-labels only instead of 20) of the https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.fetch_20newsgroups.html dataset.. Above you can see the accuracy, precision, classification report and confusion matrix of the two learned classifiers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so keeping it very short and precisely in context of your question-

Accuracy tells us, out of all the documents how many are classified correctly.

Precision tells us out of all documents which are predicted in a category, how often its correct.

Uni -gram- "nasa", "is" "space" , "agency"
bi-gram- "nasa is", "space agency"

Now lets go over the numbers, in both the cases accuracy and precision doesn't have significant difference.

But as  we can see bi-grams can give me much more information and hence can have better performance on unseen data. Try to test the model on unseen data/validation set and compare the difference.May be Try tri-grams etc also.